# Ubuntu 14.04 NFSv3 now squashing user/group, how to fix?

Tags: 14.04, nfs

I have been running Ubuntu against my ReadyNAS Pro for some time. The ReadyNAS Radiator code is based on Debian. I did not change anything on the ReadyNAS side.

I just performed the 14.04 upgrade from 13.10, and to my surprise, NFSv3 behaviour changed.

Mounts work fine as before. I can mount the filesystems as expected.

I have coordinated uid/gid on client and server side. Looking at id and ls -l UID/GID shows they are the same on both sides (1005/1000).

But if I create a new file, or attempt to access an existing file or directory, I get a client side permission failure.

Specifically, any attempt to create a new file shows user id nobody and user group nogroup, any attempt to access through a directory that isn't a+x fails, and any attempt to read a file that is not a+r fails.

I have manually added no_all_squash on the ReadyNAS side and exportfs -vr with no change. So this plus the problem starting on the upgrade suggests something on the ubuntu client side is squashing the UID/GID. But I was pretty sure squashing was a server side function.

I did notice that domain name wasn't aligned after the upgrade, so I have made sure hostname --domain returns the same on both sides.

I have run out of ideas on how to debug this.

I am reduced to reading change logs from upstream to try to figure out what changed.

Does anyone have suggestions on what to look at next? Googling this issue has not been helpful so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out. I did a tcpdump and discovered that RPC authentication was AUTH_NULL, not the expected UNIX. Now, here is the real puzzle: I had sec=sys explicitly on every NFS mount. REMOVING sec=sys returned to RPC AUTH_UNIX.

I filed a bug report on this: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1315974